# Edges of mesh with emission shader look like of low resolution

Tags: shaders, resolution

As you can see the edges of a plane mesh with emission shader don't look like a smooth straight edge.
I have noticed that generally the edges of a mesh with just a plain emission shader are not smooth.
How can fix that? 
I would like to smooth the edges out and make the emission more "blurred".

Is it about settings?
Is it about the type of Mix shading in the node editor?
Is it about the material around the emitting mesh?

My settings:

Resolution: 4096x2080
Resolution %: 200%
Samples: 300
Integrator: Branches Path Tracing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure if something is wrong with my eyes, but I don't see that the edge is more jagged than the one of the lamp.

Comment: Don't you see that the marked region looks like of low reso? The lines are not smooth, that's what my eyes see at least.

Comment: Well yes, but not more than the other edges, only that the contrast is higher. If you want to make the emission glow, you can do that in compositing by adding a Glare node.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But keep in mind that it's zoomed in so it got worse. I will try to raise the samples, 300 might be low.

Comment: I agree with gtzkw. Additionaly i think the abruptness of shading is not caused by the emmission but mostly by the unrealistic geometry of the metal part... Maybe it would help to put a solidify modifier on the metal part. (Maybe even do a bevel afterwards) Then it would have a thickness and the lighting change wouldn't look so abrupt...

Comment: OK I will test this idea Robert, thanks!